# Json encode php long contents of array

Tags: php, json

i have a problem with json_encode with php, i use php 5.2.6 and i receive from server this  data:

```
Array (… => Array ( [codIdenVerb] => 276122 [codAppe] => 778033 [codCorsoStud] => 00688 [descrizione] => PSICOLOGIA SOCIALE [crediti] => 9.0 [canale] => NESSUNA CANALIZZAZIONE [docente] => TONI ALESSANDRO [facolta] => SCIENZE POLITICHE, SOCIOLOGIA, COMUNICAZIONE [annoAcca] => 2012 [dataAppe] => 25/09/2012 .........
```

...

```
[note] => La prova scritta si svolgerà il giorno 10 settembre presso l'aula Magna a partire dalle ore 10.oo. La prova orale si svolgerà il giorno 25 settembre presso l'aula B14 a partire dalle ore 9.30. Si ricorda, inoltre, che la prenotazione su INFOSTUD per la data della prova ora è valida e necessaria per sostenere la prova scritta.
```

..

```
[dataInizioPrenotazione] => 06/05/2012 [dataFinePrenotazione] => 30/08/2012 [questionario] => false [SiglaModuloDidattico] => 1010544 ) [7] => Array…)
```

for encode i use $json_string = json_encode($data);

but the part with [note] is cut whit: "note":"La prova scritta si svolger","..."
where is the problem? how can solve? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`json_encode()` expects incoming data to be UTF-8.

The data you are passing to it is probably not UTF-8.

Find out what encoding it is in, and adjust the input encoding or use e.g. [`iconv()`](http://www.php.net/iconv) to convert the data from your original encoding to UTF-8.

Comment: Hi tnks for response but i have try this: $text = "This is the Euro symbol 'â‚¬'.";

echo 'Original : ', $text, PHP_EOL;
echo 'TRANSLIT : ', iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $text), PHP_EOL;
echo 'IGNORE   : ', iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//IGNORE", $text), PHP_EOL;
echo 'Plain    : ', iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $text), PHP_EOL;  but i see this: Original : This is the Euro symbol '‰âÂ'. 
TRANSLIT : This is the Euro symbol ' 
IGNORE : This is the Euro symbol ''. 
Plain : This is the Euro symbol '  why?

Comment: @user you mean the other way round, no? UTF-8 would have to be your *target* character set

Comment: yes you have right, i have try this: $string=iconv('ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT//IGNORE','UTF-8', "sàs");
$json_string = json_encode($string); 
print_r($json_string); but i see "s\u00c3\u00a0s" and how can see sàa? thanks for your time and patience i'm new on php.

Comment: @user `s\u00c3\u00a0s` is actually correct, it's JSON's way of encoding non-ASCII characters. When you parse the JSON using a proper parser (like jQuery's `.getJSON()` or whatever you use to fetch it), you will see the characters look okay again.

Comment: ok thanks! I have solved with your help! thank you very much indeed!